# How to position an image in mobile landscape view

Tags: css

I have several images that are positioned in mobile portrait but right of centre in mobile landscape.

I tried adjusting width, height, margin-left: nothing.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) 
{.awpcp-ad-primary-image {margin-left: 10px! Important; 
 width: 200px! Important ;}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make a container division  with justify content center and padding as required and then the image in the container with width: 100%; you should not need to use margin or padding left or right to try to center things.

Here is the best CSS feature for getting things layed out properly.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: How do I make a container division? Thanks